# Merge files with sort -m and give error if files not pre-sorted?

Tags: sorting, merge

need some help out here.

I have two files,

```
    file1.txt >
    5555555555
    1111111111
    7777777777

    file2.txt >
    0000000000
    8888888888
    2222222222
    4444444444
    3333333333
```

when I run,
        `$ sort -m file1.txt file2.txt > file-c.txt`
the output file-c.txt get the merged within file1 and file2 but it is not sorted.

```
    file-c.txt >
    0000000000
    5555555555
    1111111111
    7777777777
    8888888888
    2222222222
    4444444444
    3333333333
```

When it happens I need an error saying that the files (file1 and file2) is not sorted and the merge can't merge the files before it has been sorted. So when I run `$ sort -m file1.txt file2.txt > file-c.txt` I have to get an error saying that it cannot merge file1 and file2 to file-c because they are not yet sorted.

Hope you guys understand me :D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, you could do this:

```
DIFF1=$(diff <(cat file1.txt) <(sort file1.txt))
DIFF2=$(diff <(cat file2.txt) <(sort file2.txt))
if [ "$DIFF1" != "" ]; then
echo 'file1 is not sorted'
elif [ "$DIFF2" != "" ]; then
echo 'file2 is not sorted'
else
sort -m file1.txt file2.txt
fi
```

This works in Bash (and other shells) and does the following:

1. Set the DIFF1 variable to the output of a diff of a cat and a sort of file1 (this will be empty if the cat and sort are the same meaning if the file is sorted
2. Set the DIFF2 variable in the same manner as DIFF1 but for file2
3. Do a simple if .. elif .. else to check and see whether file1 AND file2 are sorted, and if so do a command line sort of the two

Is this what you were looking for?

EDIT: Alternately per @twalberg if your version of sort supports it, you can do this:

```
if ! sort -c file1.txt
then echo 'file1 is not sorted'
elif ! sort -c file2.txt
then echo 'file2 is not sorted'
else
sort -m file1.txt file2.txt
fi
```

Comment: Note most versions of `sort` have a `sort -c` (or `--check`) option to do a fast check whether a file is sorted. No need for the `diff` overkill... So you can do `if sort -c file.txt; then ...`